# ASP.Net login : SQL query syntax error

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am building an `sql` query in `c#` to perform login, at the end of this I get a syntax error, but I can't figure out what causes the error

```
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From bruker Where Brukernavn='" 
                      + Textbox1.Text + "' and Passord='" + TextBox2.Text"");
```

Comment: you've missed `+` before `""`

Comment: Also, beware SQL injection. Parameterize your queries.

Comment: here is a picture of the error https://i.gyazo.com/60e8e3fe52f3cfd6f8b187ae82a0deb4.png

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `"+"` and you need to pass connection string or an `SqlConnection` as a second parameter

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From bruker Where Brukernavn='" + Textbox1.Text + "' and Passord='" + TextBox2.Text +"","connectionString");
```

or

```
 SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From bruker Where Brukernavn='" + Textbox1.Text + "' and Passord='" + TextBox2.Text +"",con);
```

Since the above code is vulnerable to sql injection, please use the below code which will prevent sql injection.

```
try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connectionString");
    SqlCommand commnad = new SqlCommand("Select * From bruker Where Brukernavn=@username and Passord=@password", con);

    commnad.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Textbox1.Text.Trim);
    commnad.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Textbox2.Text.Trim);
    //rest of the code
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
  //log exception and re-throw or send a generic exception message to UI
  throw;
}
finally
{
  //close the connection
}
```

Please mark it as answer if that solves your issue.

Comment: @mxmissile  I don't know why you down voted. Making it as non-inject-able was not his question. I just gave asnswer for his question. This is not fair

Comment: @KiranB it doesn't matter if it wasn't in his question, we should be encouraging it whenever we see the opportunity.

Comment: An equally terrible mistake is that there is a password stored in plain text.

Comment: @KiranB providing a code answer, you have the responsibility to provide secure code, it helps the OP and SO in general

Comment: @christophano and mxmissile I have updated my answer based on your suggestion. I request you to upvote and encourage me and other users to do the same going forward

Comment: @KiranB I'll upvote as well; even though it's not wrapped within a `using` or a `try...catch`